# Using shared library having absolute path for cgo and mingw linker in windows

Tags: go, mingw-w64, cgo

I have a c file that includes a shared library using an absolute path:

```c
#include "c:\Program Files\Webots\include\controller\c\webots\robot.h"
```

But the linker fails with the error:

```bash
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-1323982505\000002.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\Brian\code\webots\ULMW\controllers\FGCCULM/FGCCULM.c:77: undefined reference to `wb_robot_init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The function `wb_robot_init` is available in the shared library included. I need help on how to fix this.